# Swift iOS -How To Check If SelectedSegmentedIndex Is Visible in TabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, visibility, uisegmentedcontrol, viewwillappear

I have a `tabBarController` with 2 tabs. On the 2nd tab, I have a `segmentedControl` with 2 segments. In the `viewWillAppear` of both segments, I have code that runs. What I notice is whenever I press the 2nd tab, the code from both segments run. Even if I'm on the 2nd segment, switch back to the first tab, then switch back to the 2nd tab (which means it's still showing the second segment and the first segment isn't visible), the code from the first segment still runs.

The problem seems to be when I press the tab both segment's `viewWillAppear` runs.

```
class FirstSegment: UIViewController{

viewWillAppear...{
    //do something
}
}

class SecondSegment: UIViewController{

viewWillAppear...{
    //do something
}
}
```

I tried the following code on both segments but it didn't work because they both run if I press the 2nd tab:

```
viewWillAppear...{
    //I tried a combination of these
    if self.isViewLoaded && (self.view.window != nil) {
         // run code in viewWillAppear
    }
}
```

How can I make sure the code in the `viewWillAppear` of only the visible selected segment runs?

Comment: Can you provide your code? What do you mean "the code from first/second segment"?

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov thanks for the help. On a segmentedControl each segment has its on view controller. In the viewWillAppear of each segment's vc, the viewWillAppear runs

Comment: So, you have a tab bar with 2 tabs, and a segment control in the second tab item? But segment control isn't a container for view controllers, it's only small UIKit component.

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't understand what you mean under segment control...

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov my segment control has a vc for each segment. If I select the first segment, something happens particular to that. If I press the second segment, something particular happens with that. In both situations the code in the segment's vc dictates the outcome.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol
UISegmentedControl can't have a cv inside!

Comment: Each segment is only a button

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov so how are you supposed to run code in each segment if the segments can't have their on vcs? https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov look at the layout on this blog, yes each segment is a button and each button of that segment has it's own vc https://www.pentapie.com/tutorials/swift/segment-tab-app/

Comment: No. They are only buttons(segments), and by clicking on them you handle this action. But UISegmentControl is not a container at all.

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov I don't understand what your saying. I click each segment and in each segment there is a vc, in each vc there is viewWillAppear, and then code runs. Are you saying this is not the way it's supposed to be done?

Comment: By clicking on each segment this code runs (as in example).
private func updateView() {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        remove(asChildViewController: sessionsViewController)
        add(asChildViewController: summaryViewController)
    } else {
        remove(asChildViewController: summaryViewController)
        add(asChildViewController: sessionsViewController)
    }
}

So, try to figure out your problem in this part of your whole code.

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov ok thanks for help